Do I have to register an app website?
I use Linux Mint. The "About" panel in all apps has a website link. Do I have to register on this site? Will it be against the user's terms and conditions if I don't?




No you don't have to register on those websites but they can be helpful if you need help on those apps.

Has anyone asked you to register on any website? If not, why do you think you need to?

There’s a general assumption in the free software / open source world that users are supposed to be able to use software without any additional requirement other than getting it in some way. This is articulated explicitly in the GNU project’s four freedoms:

The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0).

The reason this is referred to as freedom 0 is that in the first iteration of the free software definition, it wasn’t mentioned — it seemed so obvious! Other definitions such as the open source definition don’t state it explicitly, but it remains an underlying assumption, as can be seen for example from item 6 of the definition:

The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

A slight variant of this is the desert island test commonly used in Debian (for modification, not just use); if users are supposed to be able to modify and distribute software without contacting anyone else, it stands to reason that they can also use it without contacting anyone else.
The GPL FAQ also mentions (for GPL-licensed software) that you don’t need to agree to anything to use the software:

You are not required to agree to anything to merely use software which is licensed under the GPL.

So no, you don’t need to register with the various web sites you’ll find linked from software “About” boxes, manuals etc.
There is software which can only be used with a user registration, e.g. because it requires an online account of some kind (for example, a social media client); but you’ll know about that because you’ll be asked to log in.
